# different command line used to extract tables from an sql server file into one that is usable by mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

What is the difference between these two command line used to extract tables from a database into one that can be used by mysql ?

```
C:> mysql -u user -p PASS database_name < ms.sql
```

And

```
mysql> source ms.sql ;
```

I used to do with the former and the database created contained all information but it didn't work. the second worked fine.

Second in the first case setting default character set is examplified but I found none in the homepage of the mysql an example for the second case. I am thankful for any help available.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the commands can be referred as Batch Commands. I am pointing out the difference between them below.

First Command

```
mysql -u user -p PASS database_name < ms.sql
```

- The above command is executing two commands at a time. One is to loggin to MySQL and other one is, passing the script file to execute using OS I/O Operator '<'.
- After execution of this command it will display the sql result of the script and comes back to command prompt.(comes out of SQL
  Prompt)
- It is necessary to keep USE DB_name command in the begening of file to execute the script
- This way is useful when you want to execute a big script without logging into mysql typically most often used.

Second Command

```
mysql> source ms.sql;
```

- The above command is generally an SQL Command which will execute the script present in sql file.
- It is used if you are already in MYSQL Prompt. After executing the script it will return back to Mysql prompt only
- You may also use this command like executing the shell script something like `mysql> ./filename`

For more information please refer MySql Reference Link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html